# Skip insert (and continue) on duplicate key [T-SQL]

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get a working solution for a arguably pretty simple task:

I have a simple query like this:

```
INSERT INTO [INTRANET].[dbo].[SOME_STATUS]
   ([AUS_STATUS_VID]
  ,[AUS_STATUS_STATUS]
  ,[AUS_STATUS_JAHR]
  ,[AUS_STAUTS_END]
 )

SELECT DISTINCT CD_CLVID, '1', '2017', '0'
FROM [SNTRANET].[dbo].[SOME_DETAILS]
WHERE CD_JAHR = 2017
```

Long story short: Filling up a table with results from another table. Now it seems like, that I have inconsistent data given to me. I was trying to find a solution similar to `replace into` or `on duplicate key update` (which I was used to from MySQL). However, T-SQL doesn't seem to have this.

Is there an easy solution which just skips the dupe key and continues with the rest of the resultset?

I'm using SQLServer 2008 R2

**Edit 1**

As requested, the error-message:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_T_KB_AUSZAHLUNG_STATUS'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.T_KB_AUSZAHLUNG_STATUS'. The duplicate key value is (7463).

Comment: The best I can come with is a IF NOT EXIST (SELECT ...) BEGIN /*insert your insert :)*/ END

Comment: which column is the duplicate key?

Comment: Where are the dups coming from?  If I've read your query correctly, the select statement returns a distinct list of `CD_CLVID`s.  If `AUS_STATUS_VID` in `[INTRANET].[dbo].[SOME_STATUS]` expects unique values it should get them.  Can you provide the create table statement?  Error messages would help too.

Comment: @destination-data added the error-message. Which create table you need? for the status or details?

Comment: Both would be good. If you can throw in some sample data that recreates the error even better!

Comment: If the new records to insert are always better than the old, you can first delete from destination what exists for insert and then insert all you have. If not then you have to select to insert rows left join the destination using PK condition where PK is null to get the non existing records only and insert them

Answer (score 1):

use the ROW_NUMBER() to ensure you incoming result does not have duplicate and then the `WHERE` clause to ensure it does not exists in the destination table

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ...
FROM
(
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PK_COL ORDER BY some_col)
    FROM   SOME_TABLE
) d
WHERE d.RN = 1
AND   NOT EXISTS
      (
           SELECT *
           FROM   DEST_TABLE x
           WHERE  x.PK_COL = d.PK_COL 
      )
```

Comment: This will not help the OP. This works if the duplicates are contained within the dataset he is trying to insert from, but the issue seems to be the dataset overlaps the data already in the destination table. – SchmitzIT just now

Comment: I think distinct is more direct and more efficient

Comment: distinct does not necessary ensure the rows to insert does not have duplicate primary key value

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SQL Server Merge Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) feature. It will Insert a New Row if no match was found or Else Update the existing records for the Matches:

Example :

```
MERGE BookInventory bi
USING BookOrder bo
ON bi.TitleID = bo.TitleID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET bi.Quantity = bi.Quantity + bo.Quantity
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (TitleID, Title, Quantity)
  VALUES (bo.TitleID, bo.Title,bo.Quantity);
```

Here if a match is found in table BookInventory for a BookOrder .TitleId then the record get inserted and otherwise, the Matched record will Be updates.

You can also achieve the same using multiple statements. Like  this

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable WHERE <Condition>
BEGIN
    <Update Statements>
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     <Insert Statement>
END
```

Or in the Direct Insert, Just check the existence to skip the records that are already in the Target table

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable
SELECT * FROM SourceTable ST
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM TargetTable WHERE TargetId = ST.TargetId 
)
```

Comment: I am probably being overly pedantic but the [merge statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) is not the same thing as [a merge join](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190967(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Updated to reference Merge Statement link, rather than Merge Join as @GarethD commented.

Answer (score 1):

if the duplicate key is the `[AUS_STATUS_VID]` column then try using Alias on the tables and NOT EXISTS

```
INSERT INTO [INTRANET].[dbo].[SOME_STATUS]
   ([AUS_STATUS_VID]
  ,[AUS_STATUS_STATUS]
  ,[AUS_STATUS_JAHR]
  ,[AUS_STAUTS_END]
 )
SELECT DISTINCT S.CD_CLVID, '1', '2017', '0'
FROM [SNTRANET].[dbo].[SOME_DETAILS] S
WHERE S.CD_JAHR = 2017
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT SS.AUS_STATUS_VID FROM [INTRANET].[dbo].[SOME_STATUS] SS
  WHERE SS.AUS_STATUS_VID = S.CD_CLVID
) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [INTRANET].[dbo].[SOME_STATUS]
   ( [AUS_STATUS_VID]
    ,[AUS_STATUS_STATUS]
    ,[AUS_STATUS_JAHR]
    ,[AUS_STAUTS_END]
   )

SELECT DISTINCT D.CD_CLVID, '1', '2017', '0'
FROM [SNTRANET].[dbo].[SOME_DETAILS] D
LEFT JOIN [INTRANET].[dbo].[SOME_STATUS] S 
ON S.CD_CLVID = D.CD_CLVID 
WHERE D.CD_JAHR = 2017   
AND S.CD_CLVID is null
```

If CD_CLVID is the PK in [SNTRANET].[dbo].[SOME_DETAILS] then you would not need the distinct